# Polymer notifyPath called from fetch callback

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

My application has property

```
  myData: {
    type: Array,
  },
```

which is initialized with:

```
[{'company_name': 'Company 1'}, {'company_name': 'Company 2'}]
```

I need to trigger dom-repeat update for array at template after data loaded from backend.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myData.countries}}" as="country">
    <div>[[country.name]]</div>
</template>
```

The problem I've get with is notifyPath won't work from fetch method, i.e.:

```
var self = this;

fetch('/api/all')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(json => self.myData[1]['countries'] = json)
   .then(function() {
       // not work
       self.notifyPath("myData.1.countries", self.myData[1]['countries']);
});
```

and works OK outside fetch method:

```
self.myData[1]['countries'] = [{'country_name': 'Albania'}, {'country_name': 'Mongolia'}];
self.notifyPath("myData.1.countries", self.myData[1]['countries']);
```

Am I mistaken somewhere or maybe it should be done differently?

Comment: does this return promise? `.then(json => self.myData[1]['countries'] = json)`

Comment: I understand that this does not affect due to next .this(function() {}) executes after promise, and even if I set self.myData[1]['countries'] after (inside function() ) self.notifyPath won't work as well

Comment: Add a `catch` statement to check for any errors that might be occurring in your promise chain. Also, what is the value of `json`? Does `self.myData[1]` always exist?